# How to change TextFormField height and Font color from default on Flutter

Tags: flutter

I would like to change TextFormField height and Font color.

```
           TextFormField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  filled: true,
                  icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                  hintText: 'Nick Name',
                  labelText: 'Nick Name',
              ),
            ),
```

How can I write it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To increase `TextFormField` height, you can use `contentPadding` property inside `InputDecoration` and give value to `vertical` argument as:

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30),
```

To change font color of `label` and `hint`, you can do that using `Theme` inside `MaterialApp` as below:

```
theme: ThemeData(
      inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
            labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),

      )),
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi, where does this 'theme' attribute goes?

Answer (score 4):

you can use **contentPadding** to adjust a size and **style** property to change colour and and text related property.

```
 TextFormField(
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20), // change height
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            filled: true,
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            hintText: 'Nick Name',
            labelText: 'Nick Name',
            hintStyle:
                TextStyle(color: Colors.amber)), // change hint text color
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red), // change input text color
      ),
```